# Importance between the American Mathematical Monthly and Research Journals

Tags: graduate-admissions, journals, mathematics

I am an undergraduate and have been working with one of my math professors over the past year on proving some new results.  These results are interesting and are approachable enough to be understood by most graduate students.

My professor and I have agreed that this work can certainly be published in a "professional level" research journal (I would be first author), however because the problem is approachable and would be interesting to a wide audience (and is not highly specific) we think it could be a good fit for the American Mathematical Monthly.

I want to go to graduate school, and I am wondering if publication in the American Mathematical Monthly would carry more or less weight in graduate school admissions than publication in a journal specific to the research area of the work (dynamical systems).

I understand the AMM is geared more towards publishing expository work, however publication in the journal would tend to yield more reads than in a more specific journal (I am looking at the Journal of Dynamical Systems and Geometric Theories for example).  Which would be best to publish in, or look best to a graduate school admissions committee?

Comment: This is likely to be closed as a shopping question, but having coauthored a paper that appeared in the Monthly would be a very positive factor in your applications to graduate programs.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks, how could I change this post so that it will not be closed?

Comment: Perhaps one of the moderators will have a suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I disagree that it is a shopping question.

Comment: @Buffy but it is opinion or is there a definitive answer?

Comment: Why not pursue publishing it in both? I was considering writing an answer saying as much but I don’t know the norms of that field very well.

Comment: @nick012000 in maths it is extremely frowned upon to send the same paper to two different venues simultaneously; I would go as far as to say that would be unethical conduct. Of course the OP can try one option and then, if they don't succeed, try the other

Comment: @YemonChoi Obviously not writing the exact same paper in both; one would be a more general audience/science communication  “look at what we did” thing while the other would be more formal “this is our methodology, experimental results, and conclusions based on those results”. Does math not do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably right that more people would see something published in the Monthly than in a "research" journal. But if you are aiming primarily to optimize the positive impact this paper would have on a CV for grad school (in the U.S.) I think it would be much better to say that it has been published in a good-quality research-oriented journal, since that will attest much more strongly to the quality of the research (as opposed to attesting to general interest).

EDIT: in contrast to some other answers' implications... The Math Monthly is not at all a research journal. It is an expository and (mostly elementary) problem/puzzle-oriented journal. Publication there is viewed (in my experience, and in my own opinion) as a good thing, but no indication at all about "research potential" or such stuff. That's not the fundamental criterion for publication there!

So, if you are wanting to give evidence that you have already made (and thus in the future can make) research contributions... publication in the Monthly gets you close-to-nothing. Sure, "it's nice", but it's not at all about making significant new contributions to live subjects. It's an *entirely* different thing. It's not just "a somewhat different journal"... it's in an entirely different category.

Comment: The Math Monthly might be the right choice if the OP were interested in a math ed degree. Otherwise I can't imagine why anything publishable in a decent research journal would be submitted there.

Comment: +1.  Let me also point out that the Monthly has very high expository standards, and trying to write a paper suitable for the Monthly may be a lot more work.

Comment: (On the other hand, I think for a joint paper of an undergrad with a professor, it's hard to tease out too much about the research potential just from this, and one really relies on the letters...)

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for other academics, but I think it is unlikely to make a large difference which journal you choose.  Whenever I assess a prospective graduate student for a PhD program, if they have published papers, I read these to get an idea of how well they can write, and the level of insight in their existing work.  (Applicants for graduate school will usually have no more than a handful of publications, if any, so it is not onerous to read them all.)  Since I am reading and assessing the content of the papers directly, it really makes no difference to me what journal they are in.  Even if the student had published a good paper in a predatory journal with no real peer review process, if the content was good, it would be a good sign for their application.  (Although it would mean that the student should be advised to seek publication in a better journal.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the US and intend to go to grad school in the US, I wouldn't be too concerned about this. Few undergraduates in the US have any publications at all and so having some record of published results would make you stand out. One advantage of the MAA is that it has wide readership, whereas a more specialized journal will only be seen by a few.

But it is the quality of the work itself, not just the journal in which it is published that is important.

Also, if, as you say, the problem itself is approachable others similar to yourself would benefit from a wide audience.

However, if you aren't close to graduation, then you could explore publication in a more specialized top journal and see what reception the paper gets. You can always send it to the AMM or even JAMS later.

Actually, however, the fact that you are in a position to even ask this question suggests that your acceptance into a good graduate program is pretty much assured. A lot of us got there from more humble beginnings.

---

Caveat: The EU situation is different, as the European educational system is quite different at the BA/BS level.

Comment: What is "JAMA"?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning, Actually, JAMS, Journal of the American Mathematical Society.

Comment: @Buffy forgive me if you know more about maths journals than I do but the gulf between AMM and JAMS seems **vast** to me. JAMS aspires to be just below Annals in terms of prestige and selectivity, I think, and full professors would be happy/proud just to get **some** of their research output into it. So I am not sure about your calibration here

Comment: @YemonChoi, indeed. I picked it only because it is another general, rather than specialized, journal. And also has wide readership.

Comment: @Buffy Why do you think it has wide readership? Have you looked at what's published in it? It is a general journal, yes, but it is one which is meant for **groundbreaking research** that will interest various specialists around the world. I don't think it is sensible to be encouraging the OP to even **think** about JAMS, especially when they describe their results as "approachable enough to be understood by most graduate students. "